# What bird is this?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Location: Urban area near the [Western Ghats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Ghats), Kerala, South India.

Date: 20th April, 2017

Current Climate: Hot and humid. Occasional rains.

Brief Description:

Not large, about the size of a house sparrow. Didn't make any characteristic sound/chirping during the period of observation. Pointed,slightly curved, thin beak. Probably feeds on insects, grain, nuts. Has a black crest atop its head, similar to that of a woodpecker. Appears to have an off-white or pale yellow "mouth" (couldn't get a picture of that, sorry). Chin and throat have white feathers. Foot and legs appear dark gray, if not black. Possesses conspicuous red infraorbital patches (of feathers?) below each eye.

Additional Information:

The locality is often frequented by feral pigeons. However, this particular bird made its appearance when there were no pigeons in sight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is a [red whiskered bulbul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-whiskered_bulbul).

[image]

(image from the Wikipedia article)

The crest isn't as prominent in your pictures - maybe it has just been to the barbers.